# If I create an account on Game Of war will I lose my progress?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

I have Game of War on my Phone and I have 1.9 million power. It keeps asking me to create a account for it. So if I listen and create and account will I lose my progress or will it still stay there?

Answer (score 3):

It will stay there.

 At the moment, your game data is only saved on your phone. 
The purpose of creating an account is that if you change another phone in the future, you can still have your game data by logging in to that account because the data will be saved into the account online.

Answer (score -1):

As of 2017, you have to create an account and confirm an email sent to you after. Next time you enter the game, it will ask for your login information and you will have your data.

Any other action other than that, you'll lose data in moment you log in. i.e. if log in with an existing account.

Comment: reason for downvoting?